# WordPress archive-custom.php page not working

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am new in WordPress.
I have a custom post type and from that custom post type, one post will show in home page, and below that post there is a link. When visitors will click on that link, it will take them in a page where all posts of that custom post type will show with pagination.

What I have done so far.
- Created custom post type.

- Called one post in home page.( Upto that it's working fine. )
- Created a archive-custom.php template.

But couldn't solve that link. Php the permalink doesn't work. 
Also if I try to access the archive page by mysite.com/archive-custom.php no post shows there.

Search in Google, stackoverflow, wordpress codex . But unfortunately ended up with no result.

Any suggestions on how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Better way to develop archive page for a custome postype is, copy the code from archive.php (of coarse from your current theme folder) and paste it on newly created page "archive-yourpostype.php" . Then start tweaking on the code.

Comment: Thanks Arka. Actually did same as you advised

Comment: try to re-save pretty permalinks from Settings-> Permalinks.

Comment: First changed parmalink and then saved as default

Answer (score 0):

From your other post, your post type is called latestnews. When you look at the [Template Hierarchy](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/) (which BTW you have to read thouroughly), you can create a custom archive page for your custom poist type. For this to work, `has_archive` have to be set to `true` when registering your post type.

Now, lets look at what is happening. You have a custom archive page, `arhive-custom.php`. When you directly access

> mysite.com/archive-custom.php

It will fail, as it is wrong permalink structure.

Also, wordpress will look for the custom post type `custom`, which will outright fail, because that post type does not exist.

If your post type is called latestnews, then your archive page should be called archive-latestnews.php